# Why does groupByKey operation have always 200 tasks?

Tags: apache-spark

Whenever I do a `groupByKey` on an RDD, it gets split up in 200 jobs, even if the original table is quite large, e.g. 2k partitions and tens of millions of rows.

Moreover, the operation seems to get stuck on the last two tasks which take extremely long to compute.

Why is it 200? How to increase it and will it help?

Answer (score 7):

This setting comes from `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, which is the number of partitions to use when grouping, and has a [default setting of 200](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options), but can be increased. This may help, it will be dependent on the cluster and data.

The last two tasks taking very long will be due to skewed data, those keys contain many more values. Can you use `reduceByKey` / `combineByKey` rather than `groupByKey`, or parallelize the problem differently?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The solution you gave works for joining DataFrames, but doesn't work for RDDs. I ended up using partitionBy(n_part) before joining to explicitly specify partitioner (and shuffle). This way groupByKey doesn't do partitioning itself and runs on whatever number of partitions is given. Can you please update your answer to include this? As to the skewed data, we just filtered out extraordinarily large groups (there were 0.01% of those)