# Why is the number of partitions after groupBy 200? Why is this 200 not some other number?

Tags: apache-spark

It's Spark 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.

Why is the number of partitions after `groupBy` transformation 200 in the following example?

```
scala> spark.range(5).groupByKey(_ % 5).count.rdd.getNumPartitions
res0: Int = 200
```

What's so special about `200`? Why not some other number like `1024`?

I've been told about [Why does groupByKey operation have always 200 tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31265927/1305344) that asks specifically about `groupByKey`, but the question is about the "mystery" behind picking `200` as the default not why there are 200 partitions by default.

Comment: It looks like it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31265927/1305344

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does groupByKey operation have always 200 tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265927/why-does-groupbykey-operation-have-always-200-tasks)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is set by spark.sql.shuffle.partitions

In general whenever you do a spark sql aggregation or join which shuffles data this is the number of resulting partitions.

It is constant for your entire action (i.e. it is not possible to change it for one transformation and then again for another).

See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options for more information

Comment: I don't think that there is a particular reason. They seem to have a thing for 200 but nothing related to some sort of optimization. I think that a benchmark needs to be made in order to maybe get something out of it

Comment: In general, spark defaults are aimed at working out of the box in a local computer (1 node). They should be configured to something better when tuning your cluster.

Comment: `spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold` is also 200. I don't think it's a coincidence.

Comment: This is interesting too -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6026

Comment: The link to the docs is now http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options