# Which properties has Spark DataFrame after join of two DataFrames with same partitioning?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say, I have two Spark DataFrames with column `some_col`

```
df_1 = df_1.repartition(50, 'some_col')
df_2 = df_2.repartition(50, 'some_col')

df_3 = df_1.join(df_2, on='some_col')
```

I thought that `df_3` should be also partitioned by `some_col` and has 50 partitions but my experiments show that at least the last condition is not true. Why does it happen?

What happens in terms of time-consuming operations (re-partitioning or re-location) can happen after

```
df_3 = df_3.repartition(50, 'some_col')
```

Comment: Why do you think `df_3` should have 50 partitions? What says `df_3.rdd.getNumPartitions()` right after join?

Comment: I found that `df_3.rdd.getNumPartitions()` is equal `spark.default.parallelism`. It looks strange.. Why does it happen? It looks much easier to make join inside same partitions!

Comment: It's always equal to `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359344/why-is-the-number-of-partitions-after-groupby-200-why-is-this-200-not-some-othe

Comment: But why does shuffle happen? According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843509/1849828) it's not necessary to shuffle due to right partitioning, isn't it?

Comment: The shuffle happens, because spark requires 200 partitions (so it need to be repartitioned). You can try setting parameter to 50 and see if shuffling still occures (I don't know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

condition that " df_3 should be also partitioned by some_col and has 50 partitions " will only be true if df_1 and df_2 have the partitions with same values for "some_col" i.e. if df_1 has 2 partitions : [(1,2)], [(3,1),(3,7)], (such that some_col values are 1, 3) then df_2 needs to have partitions with some_col values 1,3. If that is the case then on joining df_1 and df_2, it will produce df_3 with same number of partition as in df_1 or df_2.

In all other cases it will try to create a default 200 partitions and shuffle the whole join operation.

for clarity you can try following example:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(1,2), (1,9), (2, 3), (3,4)])
df1 = rdd1.toDF(['a', 'b'])
df1 = df1.repartition(3, 'a')
df1.rdd.glom().collect() #outputs like:
>> [[Row(a=2,b=3)], [Row(a=3,b=4)], [Row(a=1,b=2), Row(a=1,b=9)]]

df1.rdd.getNumPartitions()
>>3

rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(1,21), (1,91), (2, 31), (3,41)])
df2 = rdd2.toDF(['a', 'b'])
df2 = df2.repartition(3, 'a')
df2.rdd.glom().collect() #outputs like:
>> [[Row(a=2,b=31)], [Row(a=3,b=41)], [Row(a=1,b=21), Row(a=1,b=91)]]

df2.rdd.getNumPartitions()
>>3


df3 = df1.join(df2, on='a')
df3.rdd.glom().collect() #outputs like:
>> [[Row(a=2,b=3,b=31)], [Row(a=3,b=4,b=41)], [Row(a=1,b=2,b=21), Row(a=1,b=9,b=91)]]
df21.rdd.getNumPartitions()
>>3
```

Comment: Thx! Actually it's much more clear now. Am I right that if some_col in df1 and df2 has not the same values (e.g. [1, 3] and [1, 2, 3])  it will always cause a shuffle?