# Why there are mostly 200 tasks in stages for Structured Streaming even I change the default configuration by setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, shuffle, spark-structured-streaming

I have a  spark structured streaming application run in yarn mode.

I am trying to reduce the number of tasks, and I notice that most stages have 200 tasks. And I have set `--conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=40" --conf  "spark.default.parallelism=40"`, but this does not work.

the code like:

```
df.withWatermark("ts", "5 minutes")
    .groupBy(window($"ts", "5 minutes"),  $"user",... )
    .agg(count($"A"), sum($"B"))
    .select("window.start", "window.end",... )
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("update")
    .foreach(writer())
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)
    .trigger()
    .start()
```

Comment: Hi, add some code pls.

Comment: Can you share the .explain pls? or spark ui output?

Comment: When I delete the checkpointDir. on hdfs and run again, It works, but I can not explain it !!! Can you give me some advice please?

Comment: interesting. not sure what to make of it

Comment: what works? edit your question to reflect this pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the number of partitions after groupBy 200? Why is this 200 not some other number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359344/why-is-the-number-of-partitions-after-groupby-200-why-is-this-200-not-some-othe)

Answer (score 2):

When you use option(*"checkpointLocation", checkpointDir*) you need to delete the *checkpointDir* in order to allow take effect the new value of *spark.default.parallelism*. Spark uses the existing checkpoint information when restart the stream and this imply maintaining 200 (or whatever previous value) partitions. At least Spark 3.1.1 can not "reshape" the stream...

Answer (score 0):

Task is a piece of work/process on a partition. In an ideal situation for a given stage, number of tasks is directly proportional to number of partitions. So, please check number of partitions in your DataFrame. Hope this helps.

```
syntax: df.rdd.getNumPartitions
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41359344/1305344).

Comment: Hi @Jacek Laskowski, thanks for replying. My bad, I've read this article of yours a days ago. I should have posted the same here :) https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-performance-tuning-groupBy-aggregation.html