# Different result in each run (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a data frame as a result of multiple joins. And I want to investigate for duplicates. But each time when I investigate it the data frame looks different. In particular, the following command leads to different `IDs` but the number of results stays constant.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# User input for number of rows
n_a = 10
n_a_c = 5
n_a_c_d = 3
n_a_c_e = 4

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema_a = StructType([StructField("id1", StringType(), True)])
schema_a_b = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("extra", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
schema_a_c = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id3", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
schema_a_c_d = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id3", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id4", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
schema_a_c_e = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id3", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id5", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

# Create a list of rows with increasing integer values for "id1" and a constant value of "1" for "id2"
rows_a = [(str(i),) for i in range(1, n_a + 1)]
rows_a_integers = [str(i) for i in range(1, n_a + 1)]
rows_a_b = [(str(i), str(1), "A") for i in range(1, n_a + 1)]


def get_2d_list(ids_part_1: list, n_new_ids: int):
    rows = [
        [
            (str(i), str(i) + "_" + str(j))
            for i in ids_part_1
            for j in range(1, n_new_ids + 1)
        ]
    ]
    return [item for sublist in rows for item in sublist]


rows_a_c = get_2d_list(ids_part_1=rows_a_integers, n_new_ids=n_a_c)
rows_a_c_d = get_2d_list(ids_part_1=[i[1] for i in rows_a_c], n_new_ids=n_a_c_d)
rows_a_c_e = get_2d_list(ids_part_1=[i[1] for i in rows_a_c], n_new_ids=n_a_c_e)

# Create the DataFrame
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a, schema_a)
df_a_b = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_b, schema_a_b)
df_a_c = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_c, schema_a_c)
df_a_c_d = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_c_d, schema_a_c_d)
df_a_c_e = spark.createDataFrame(rows_a_c_e, schema_a_c_e)

# Join everything
df_join = (
    df_a.join(df_a_b, on="id1")
    .join(df_a_c, on="id1")
    .join(df_a_c_d, on="id3")
    .join(df_a_c_e, on="id3")
)

# Nested structure
# show
df_nested = df_join.withColumn("id3", f.struct(f.col("id3")))

for i, index in enumerate([(5, 3), (4, 3), (3, None)]):
    remaining_columns = list(set(df_nested.columns).difference(set([f"id{index[0]}"])))
    df_nested = (
        df_nested.groupby(*remaining_columns)
        .agg(f.collect_list(f.col(f"id{index[0]}")).alias(f"id{index[0]}_tmp"))
        .drop(f"id{index[0]}")
        .withColumnRenamed(
            f"id{index[0]}_tmp",
            f"id{index[0]}",
        )
    )

    if index[1]:
        df_nested = df_nested.withColumn(
            f"id{index[1]}",
            f.struct(
                f.col(f"id{index[1]}.*"),
                f.col(f"id{index[0]}"),
            ).alias(f"id{index[1]}"),
        ).drop(f"id{index[0]}")

# Investigate for duplicates in id3 (should be unique)
df_test = df_nested.select("id2", "extra", f.explode(f.col("id3")["id3"]).alias("id3"))

for i in range(5):
    df_test.groupby("id3").count().filter(f.col("count") > 1).show()
```

The last command prints in one of two my case different results. Sometimes:

```
+---+-----+
|id3|count|
+---+-----+
|6_4|    2|
+---+-----+
```

And sometimes

```
+---+-----+
|id3|count|
+---+-----+
|9_3|    2|
+---+-----+
```

If it helps I use Databricks Runtime Version 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)

Moreover, there can be no duplicate to my understanding based on the design of the code. The found duplicate seems to be a bug!?

Maybe as a potential proof that the join does not result in any duplicates:

```
df_join.groupby("id3", "id4", "id5").count().filter(f.col("count") > 1).show()
```

is empty

Comment: Can you share how `df` is defined? Pyspark is lazy so if there is anything that is non-deterministic before that could lead to you getting different results each time.

Comment: I get more and more of the feeling it is because of a data overload

Comment: I left join multiple tables and afterward, I group the results. After all joining before the grouping I have 26415711 rows some fields are arrays of structs.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if your constant 200 figure is related to the default `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` value (which is 200) https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359344/why-is-the-number-of-partitions-after-groupby-200-why-is-this-200-not-some-othe and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265927/why-does-groupbykey-operation-have-always-200-tasks

Comment: @s_pike: Indeed. If I lower the number of partitions the number of duplicates equal to the number of partitions

Comment: Do I need the shuffling?

Comment: The shuffling always happens with the `groupBy` - it's not something you choose. If you want to get the same results each time you could try putting an `orderBy` in. I'm not sure why it doesn't give you more though, if they exist.

Comment: But in the end, the grouping and joining would not lead to any duplicates. It seems that the partitioning causes this

Comment: By look different do you mean the 1st row or last row is not same ID. This is expected since spark randomly splits data to executors and the order of reduce step is random. Try using sort on ID's and see if the issue still persists

Comment: @glory9211 By Different I mean. It always tells me there are duplicates. But each time, I let the list of duplicates be shown, the displayed IDs are completely different. Not just the order

Comment: That's an interesting problem. Can you share some reproducible case in your question.

Comment: That's very difficult as it seems only to appear for relatively large data sets. But in end, I had multiple full joins. After that, I compacted them to an array of structs using multiple group by

Comment: The only strange thing I see in your snippet is that you use `f.col('count')` instead of `df.col('count')`, but I've never experienced non-reproducible behavior for such a reason. What does `df.groupby('id').count().filter(f.col('count')>1).explain(True)` print?

Comment: @LazlooXp in order for us to best help you investigate what's going on, we probably need some example of what is occurring. can you edit your question to include a sample of the different outputs you're seeing (with `ID`) and then also show us those IDs in the original df? It would also be helpful for us to see how you're creating your df – i know that in theory it shouldn't matter, but it's best to look into every possibility

Comment: For me this code is deterministic and should always return the same results, i suspect that the problem is coming before this line of code, some functions in spark are not deterministic and could give different results, like first, ranks ..., you should give a reproducible code/data and add it here.

Comment: Finally, I could come up with a code example. Sorry, it is very complex. But it seems to be a strange bug in the first place :D @DerekO

Answer (score 3):

The way the column `"id3"` is constructed is random, so for each execution you will get different results, you need to define an orderBy() to get the same results, so after adding an orderBy() on that column like below:

```
df_nested = df_join.withColumn("id3", f.struct(f.col("id3"))).orderBy("id3")
```

Now you will always get the same results, for multiple executions.

Remember, spark evaluation is lazy, so the Dag will be re-constructed for each action, in this case it's the show().

So if your code is not deterministic, it will give different outputs each time.

Comment: That helps with the first point now that the results are consistent. However, the result indicates that id3 == "8_3" exists twice. Which should by the design of the code not be possible

Comment: Which part of my code to you consider "constructed in random"?

Comment: Shall I open a new Question regarding the duplicates?